# Searching for a '$' in a string

Tags: java

How can I make this working. I want to check if a string contains a $ sign.

```
if(messageSuccess.îndexOf('$')>0)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
No signature of method: java.lang.String.îndexOf() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [$]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking a method that does not exist :`îndexOf()` change it to `indexOf()`, change **î** to **i**

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not allowed to comment but this is actually just a comment / Note: i think you got a typo there: with: `îndexOf('$')` 
try using: `indexOf('$')`